# How hath this one known letters - not having learned?

Tags: john, jesus

The Jews marvelled at the feast, John 7:15, and asked:

> How hath this one known letters - not having learned? [Young's Literal]
>
> Πως ουτος γραμματα οιδεν μη μεμαθηκως  [EGNT, Stephens 1550]

How, indeed, did Jesus have *grammata* [Strong 1121] 'that which has been written' [Thayer],
without ever having *manthano* [Strong 3129] 'learned or been apprised' [Thayer] ?

What do the words themselves, in this text, tell us? Do those words, themselves, answer the question?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer from a purely linguistic aspect? Actually, I don't think there's much to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To your comments above: Note that in John 7 he is an adult, not "the age of twelve." A similar comment is made in Luke 2. In ***that*** story, Jesus is twelve.

To the question: They may well have meant that they don't remember him being a student at one of their recognized schools or studying under any of their recognized teachers. Note Paul the Apostle's awareness of his own scholarly pedigree (Acts 22:3; Philippians 3:5; Galatians 1:14).

This response is only in John's Gospel - Luke's account of Jesus' visit to the temple doesn't include anything about whether he had studied or had "letters."

So why would they ask "How has he learned (perfect active) *the writings* (i.e. he is a teacher) but he has never studied?"

The important word here seems to be "study." Μανθανω almost always seems to refer to something that one person has learned from another person. Perhaps that's the key - Jesus had never "studied with" anyone in the way their teachers had studied.

Beneath all these word studies (which can only go so far) it's worth thinking about what the mindset is behind this question. Here we can get a pretty good idea. Jesus is speaking to (and a part of) a people concerned with sources of authority. The earliest rabbis seem to constantly be asking themselves questions like "where did he get that from?" or "who said that first?" or "what text proves that point?" There are hundreds upon hundreds of discussions about learning and studying in the earliest sources. What a surprise it must have been to hear someone teach with authority from God!

Comment: (+1) Your last two sentences bear thinking about. I think you have it, right there, myself. Thank you.

Comment: It would also be good to actually add citations to sources. Perhaps cite scientific papers illustrating these concepts. Keep in mind that this is not a religious site, so accepting things on faith is irrelevant here. We care about the historical, linguistic, and literary context, and hermeneutical methods of interpreting the texts. If no one has shared this with you yet, [this is a good article summarizing what this site is all about and some of our distinctives](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/).